# Firefox css linear-gradient property over part of div instead of whole div?

Tags: css, gradient

Please see the images below. Notice how the inner gradient in Chrome permeates only for only 10px from the top to bottom whereas in Firefox, the gradient permeates throughout the whole div.

I want to make the Firefox gradient to behave like Chrome gradient.

Is there some way in Firefox to do this?

The following are my css code for Chrome and Firefox.

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 10, from(#F5F6F7), to(white));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F5F6F7, white);
```

**Chrome**
[image: Chrome]

**Firefox**
[image: Firefox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be looking for something like this:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CCC 0%, #FFFFFF 10%);
```

You were just missing the *color stop* arguments.

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kd8Vf/3/

I changed the colour to #CCC and the background to black so you can see it better. Change back the colours accordingly.

Also see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: [gradient example](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#034769+0,63add0+10,ffffff+27;Custom)

```
    background: #034769;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #034769 0%, #63add0 10%, #ffffff 27%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#034769), color-stop(10%,#63add0), color-stop(27%,#ffffff));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #034769 0%,#63add0 10%,#ffffff 27%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #034769 0%,#63add0 10%,#ffffff 27%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #034769 0%,#63add0 10%,#ffffff 27%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #034769 0%,#63add0 10%,#ffffff 27%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#034769', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );
```